# Ruby on Rails new app creation failing on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byebug

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and am trying to make an app.
I ran rails new myApp, and it ran into a problem when installing byebug.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
      0 [main] rm 5012 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to rm.exe.stackdump
make: [clean-static] Error 5 (ignored)
      0 [main] rm 4148 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to rm.exe.stackdump
make: [clean] Error 5 (ignored)

make "DESTDIR="
generating byebug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
cc1.exe: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:217:0,
                 from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:29,
                 from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./byebug.h:4,
                 from breakpoint.c:1:
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/win32.h:320:44: error: 'struct timespec' declared inside parameter list
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/win32.h:320:44: error: its scope is only thisdefinition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/win32.h:321:43: error: 'struct timespec' declared inside parameter list
make: *** [breakpoint.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-4.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/byebug-4.0.5/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing byebug (4.0.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '4.0.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So it looks like the compiler is treating warnings as errors, and byebug has a warning? And I need to configure the compiler to not treat warnings as errors?

Comment: Any chance you've installed [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) for compiling libraries?

Comment: I just installed it. It gives the same error.

Comment: My suggestion was going to be to uninstall it if you had it installed. https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/119

Answer (score 1):

You should try to uninstall/reinstall DevKit for Windows as MarsAtomic adviced.
For Mac what worked for me was running
`xcode-select --install`
and specifying `github: 'deivid-rodriguez/byebug'` for byebug in Gemfile (not sure that it's necessary though).